# Theme-Check plugin using MY_THEME check error genrate

Tags: errors

I have created plugin in require file **custom-post**  & **shortcode** but theme cheaker error genrate as below .

> WARNING: The theme uses the add_shortcode() function. Custom post-content shortcodes are plugin-territory functionality.
>
> REQUIRED: The theme uses the register_post_type() function, which is plugin-territory functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I found two similar files in theme folders remove it file and Check my theme in Theme checker and issue solved.

Comment: Please **STOP** adding everything in a blockquote. Text is text and should be treated as such. Code is code and should go into a code block. If you are quoting someone, in other words, directly using someone else's words, that piece of text needs to go in a blockquote. Thats it